# Cassandra + Hector: How to navigate/jump backwards in the result?

Tags: nosql, cassandra, hector

I would be thankfull for advice, how to navigate backwards with get_slice (columns):

If I have these colum names `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12` and I have the start column/key `8` and want to query 4 columsn, I want to get the results `8 7 6 5` or `5 6 7 8` (order does not matter), but I need to navigate backwards.

(Just to clarify, I only have start column/key = `8`. I do not know colum `5` so I could query with start column/key = `5`. 5 is unknown here therefore I need to query backwards, as described...)

How to do this? the "reversed=true" seems only to return the results "reversed" in this example this would be `11 10 9 8`. This is not what I want, I need to move the cursor backwards. How to do this?

Thank you very much!

Jens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/jbohman/logsandra/wiki/Pagination-in-Cassandra